# How do I get these to act on their own in their separate containers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, click

I am a javascript/jquery novice and what I am trying to figure out is when you click the plus or minus buttons the numbers increase/decrease. However I have two sets of these in different containers but they both change their values when clicking on just one set. How can I separate these?

I looked up this javascript/jquery code on stackoverflow to make the plus/minus buttons to work and now I would like to get insight on how to make these work separately. Please help? Any help is appreciated!

Here is my demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hyona/yerfdkvk/

```
<div class="container">
  <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
  <input type='text' name='quantity' value='1' class='qty' />
  <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
  <input type='text' name='quantity' value='1' class='qty'/>
  <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</div>


//CSS Styling
.container {
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.qty {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type='button'] {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}



$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      if (currentVal < 20)
      {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
        $('.qtyminus').val("-").removeAttr('style');
      }
      else
      {
        $('.qtyplus').val("+").css('color','#aaa');
      }
    } else {
      $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(1);
    }
  });

  $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) {
      $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
      $('.qtyplus').val("+").removeAttr('style');
    } else {
      $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(1);
      $('.qtyminus').val("-").css('color','#aaa');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please separate your code by type. Also please only include code related to the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Within your event handler, you are using selectors like `$('.qtyplus')` and `$('input[name='+fieldName+']')`, which select *all* matching elements. To restrict to just the ones within the clicked element's container, use the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) methods:

```
$(this).closest('.container').find('input[name='+fieldName+']')
```

...where `this` is automatically set to be the clicked element.

(For your current HTML structure you could use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead, but I wouldn't recommend it because `.closest(...).find(...)` will cope better with more complicated nested structures so you're less likely to need to change the JS if you change the HTML.)

In context:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
    var fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var container = $(this).closest('.container');
    var field = container.find('input[name='+fieldName+']');    
    var currentVal = parseInt(field.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      if (currentVal < 20) {
        field.val(currentVal + 1);
        container.find('.qtyminus').val("-").removeAttr('style');
      } else {
        container.find('.qtyplus').val("+").css('color','#aaa');
      }
    } else {
      field.val(1);
    }
  });

  $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    var fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var container = $(this).closest('.container');
    var field = container.find('input[name='+fieldName+']');    
    var currentVal = parseInt(field.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) {
      field.val(currentVal - 1);
      container.find('.qtyplus').val("+").removeAttr('style');
    } else {
      field.val(1);
      container.find('.qtyminus').val("-").css('color','#aaa');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
  <input type='text' name='quantity' value='1' class='qty' />
  <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
  <input type='text' name='quantity' value='1' class='qty'/>
  <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</div>
```

Note that if you find yourself calling jQuery methods with the same selector more than once in the same function it is generally better to use a variable to cache the result, as shown above.

There is no need to call `e.preventDefault()` in a `type="button"` element's click handler, because there is no default behaviour, so I've removed that from your code.

(Note also that the logic you are using to set the +/- button styles/colours is incomplete (you don't reset them if the user types a non-numeric value into the field), but that has nothing to do with what you're asking so I'll leave fixing it as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.